# Group by Help in R and Keeping all columns

Tags: r

I have a large dataset with 4161512 rows and 10 columns. I am trying to group my dataset based on two columns which are character data type.I could make the grouping but I get only three rows as output, I looking for other 7 columns also which are related to grouped by columns.

Below code which gives me only the three columns (Manufacture, Name, Pay) but I also want other 7 column so that I can have 10 columns in my data table including the grouped columns.

```
Newname = Dt %>% 
  group_by(Manufacturer,Name) %>% 
  summarise(Payments=sum(Payments))
```

Please help Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can either 1) group by all the columns you want to keep or 2) join the "lost" columns back to the grouped dataframe (Newname) using left_join.

Comment: @friep suggested things I have done before. But could you provide a reproducible example that people could base their answers off of?

Comment: You are using `summarize`. This is the operation that removes the other 7 columns, because you don't do anything with them. This doesn't really have anything to do with the `group_by`, as the question would suggest.

Comment: I was trying with both the option  but I couldn't able to achieve I used Mutate  do reach my output. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Use `mutate` instead of `summarise` after grouping the data

```
Newname = Dt %>% 
  group_by(Manufacturer,Name) %>% 
  mutate(PaymentsSum = sum(Payments))
```